# Searchbar does not align itself to the center when zoomed-in, just stays put

Tags: html, css

The following is the code, i need to have the searchbar aligned to the center when zoomed in or out, should be in the center by default in any computer... any ideas how...
.............................................................................

```css
.search {
   
   text-align: center;
   
  }
     
#searchbox {
   width: 960px; 
   text-align: center;
   }
             
#searchbox input {
      outline: none;
      }

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {                                                                       color: transparent;
                                        }

input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
                              color: transparent;
                             }

input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
                               color: transparent;
                              }

#searchbox input[type="text"] {
                               background image:transparent;
                               border:2px solid #f2f2f2;
                      font:strong 15px Times New Roman, Times, serif;
          color: #f2f2f2;
          width: 560px;
          padding: 14px 17px 12px 30px;
          -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
          -moz-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
           border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1.5px #fff;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
          -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
           -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
         transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
        }
#searchbox input[type="text"]:focus {
         background: transparent;
         border: 2px solid #f7f7f7;
         width: 750px;
              padding-left: 10px;
         }

#button-submit{
      background: url('img/slider-arrow-right.png') no-repeat;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: -40px;
      border-width: 0px;
      width: 43px;
      height: 45px;
     }
```

```html
<div class = "search">
<form id="searchbox" method="get" action="/search" autocomplete="off">
<input name="q" type="text" size="15" placeholder="Enter keywords here..." />
<input id="button-submit" type="submit" value=""/> 
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Just remove  #searchbox width and it will work fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you may put it in a `text-align:center` parent `div` and make its `display` as `inline-block`:

**Note**

Its better to remove the `width: 960px;` decleration from `#searchbox`.

```css
.parent{
   text-align: center;
}
.search{   
   display:inline-block;
}
     
 #searchbox {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
 }
             
 #searchbox input {
   outline: none;
 }

 input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: transparent;
 }

 input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
   color: transparent;
 }
 
 input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
   color: transparent;
 }

 #searchbox input[type="text"] {
   background image:transparent;
   border:2px solid #f2f2f2;
   font:strong 15px Times New Roman, Times, serif;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   width: 560px;
   padding: 14px 17px 12px 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
   border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 1.5px #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
   transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
}
#searchbox input[type="text"]:focus {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #f7f7f7;
  width: 750px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#button-submit{
  background: url('img/slider-arrow-right.png') no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0px;
  width: 43px;
  height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class = "search">
        <form id="searchbox" method="get" action="/search" autocomplete="off">
            <input name="q" type="text" size="15" placeholder="Enter keywords here..." />
            <input id="button-submit" type="submit" value=""/> 
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `margin` for your `form` and `input`:

```
#searchbox {
  width: 960px; 
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#searchbox input {
  outline: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

but your `searchbox` and `input` have fixed width and on small-screen devices it'll looking not good! in this case you can use `width: auto` for small screens.
[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/8Lyun0vb/) with fixed width (your values)
[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/dx6jsyja/) with auto width